# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') when using Socket.io and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm working to setup a Socket.io connection through React but I keep running into this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlcs9.png)

App.jsx:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { socket } from './socket'
import UserList from './components/UserList'
import UserSearch from './components/UserSearch'
import userService from './services/users'

const App = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState(null)
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await userService.login({
        username, password
      })
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      setUser(null)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
    }
    catch (exception) {
      setMsg('invalid credentials')
    }
  }

  const handleInvite = () => {
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    userService.getAll().then(users =>
      setUsers(users)  
    )
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect()
    socket.on('connect', console.log('connected'))
    socket.on('disconnect', console.log('disconnected'))
    return () => {
      socket.off('connect', console.log('connected1'))
      socket.off('disconnect', console.log('disconnected'))
      socket.disconnect()
    }
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <UserSearch search={search} handleSearch={({ target }) => setSearch(target.value)}/>
      <UserList users={users} search={search}/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

socket.js:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

const URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? undefined : 'http://localhost:3001'

export const socket = io(URL, {
autoConnect: false
})
```

Backend index.js:

```
const app = require('./app')
const config = require('./utils/config')
const logger = require('./utils/logger')
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {cors: { origin: "http://localhost:5173"}})

server.listen(config.PORT, () =\> {
logger.info(`Server running on ${config.PORT}`)
})

io.on('connection', (socket) =\> {
logger.info('a user connected')
socket.on('disconnect', () =\> {
logger.info('user disconnected')
})
})
```

I've tried to debug and trace to see where the undefined is coming from, but with no luck. When I remove socket.connect(), the error doesn't appear so I'm assuming that it has something to do with the initial connection? I can't figure out why it's giving me an undefined error.

Comment: what is this `=\>`  in your Backend index.js? Is this a typo?

Comment: how is the "socket.on" working, does it need a function, socket.on('connect', () => console.log('connected'))

Comment: @nuser137 yeah the Stack overflow added a \ in my arrow functions for some reason

Comment: @Azzy This was this issue! Thank you so much